# how to find non-Differentiable points on a plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, plot

I'm working on a plot, plotted by matplotlib. it's a curve that has some non-differentiable points on it.

[image]

I'm looking for a way to find those point for different plots. can anyone help?

Comment: in what way is you're data given? just x and y points? If yes finding points that are not differentiable can just be a estimation ...

Comment: yes, these are just x and y points

Comment: that could mean two things: either (like pointed out in my first comment) you say the points estimate a function you want to estimate the non differentiable points for , or every point which is not exactly between its predecessor and successor is not differentiable. You can imagine that, if you zoom in far enough into the plot you would find a "buckling" in the plot. I assume you want the first one?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for the first one